# DynamoDB design - updating too many records

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on designing a database schema for DynamoDB. Perhaps because I very used to relational databases I can't wrap my head around the correct way to do this. 
Here is an example of my idea. 
Say I've got the data for a employee-employer table. 
I have one access pattern - given an employee id; tell me all the info about that employee including their employer and the employers associated information such as phone, address etc.

```
PK                                    Data
employee id                           employee name, employee salary, employee address, employer name, employer address, employer phone number.
```

And every employer will have many many employees (can be up to 100,000)
The problem is - what if an employer changes addresses. I will then have to go into every employee to change the employers information.

I understand that maybe I should make the employer my Sort key, and I can then even use that as a GSI PK so it will easy to get all the documents with that employer. 
But I don't want to do that - because that will still be updating many records, whereas in a traditional RDBS I would have employees with a foreign key to the employers in a separate table and it would only have to be changed in one record.
Is there a design pattern I can use to only update my employers information in one place?
Thanks!!

Comment: How about make employer as pk? and with dynamodb you should forget RDBMS, remove all thoughts from your mind. believe me-:).

Comment: Thanks @Alex! If I would make employer my pk, I guess I would have to make my SK the employee. And then if I would have all my employee and employer information in the attribute, so I would still have to update multiple records I think. Is there a way to do it where I don't have to update multiple records?

Comment: Because of your access pattern, No.also this kind of data(employer address) is not frequently changed. and don't forget to take advantage of  nosql workbench for dynamodb.could be helpful